# Where do I ask a question about earphones and the purposes of its 3 types of holes in it?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The question about earphones:

> I have JBL earphones. See image. I there are 3 holes on it. One is on back side, one is on side (grey mesh, highlighted by yellow arrow) and a small round hole in center (highlighted by pink).
>
> [image]
>
> I don't even know which of them is speaker and how to properly insert it in my ears. So I want to know which one is actually speaker so I can understand how to use it properly.
>
> I had always assumed that the grey mesh (yellow) is the speaker. But now I feel suspicious because in my 2 years of usage, I suddenly realized that I can hear more sound from pink highlighted hole as compared to grey mesh (yellow).

I searched about it, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Is there a site where I can ask about it?

Comment: Not quite the answer you'd want but - generally 'great' and successful questions often involve research

Figured that the design was similar to an apple earpod (and the manuals for this would be useful), and its a JBL T205 (via a clever google search). I did a quick check and found there was no manual  but wouldn't a yourtube review be useful here? I mean other than  the obvious protrusion  under the yellow arrow (more visible on the left earbud) being designed for normal human earcanals?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek no. Reviews didn't tell anything about it. They talked about all other stuff.

Comment: @Mark I don't think support on consumer electronics is in EE's scope.

Comment: @Mast do you know any room where people can discuss these things?

Comment: You are question banned from the one community where this question is within scope.

Comment: @Ramhound which community would that be?

Comment: I think he's talking about Electronics SE

Comment: Tbh, the edit clarifies things a bit and it goes from "how do I wear my headphones" to ... well the start of a good question about headphone design and acoustics. Not sure what's a great place to start "SEwise" but you're probably looking at a bass port.

Comment: It's been over a year and still no answers! Someone pls tell us what the holes are for! 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As much as it's Stack Exchanges aim to the the repository for answering every question possible, there's questions that are better asked elsewhere.

For product specific questions like this, I'd highly recommend asking the product manufacturer directly.  JBL is a well-established brand with a good support site.

I'd ask them directly.

https://support.jbl.com/gb/en/

Answer (score 1):

A concern I would have here, aside from the topicality of a potential site to post it to is it's essentially "I have this image of a pair of headphones - how do I use them" or "what are these extra holes in my headphones?"

While I guess a hypothetical 'general' consumer electronics site (which for some reason never got off the ground) might have this in topicality. If such a site existed - it might be worth discussing practical issues.

With the current iteration of the question I still feel like the question needs development and I'm not quite sure where would be a good place for this, but you're essentially asking about bass vents or ports, which might be a useful starting point in doing your own research. This *isn't* an electronics question - that much I can confirm. If you were designing a headphone from scratch, I'd almost suggest an engineering or physics site, but from this particular frame of reference I don't think it would be a good fit.

If you're doing your own research - "Bass vent(ing)" or "bass ports" would be useful search phrases. "iem" and "earbud" are interchangeable here. I'd suggest looking at specialist headphone fora, they're good sources of information but sometimes a little prickly and some of the thing you see there aren't based on common sense... so take what you see with a pinch of salt.